# Podspec for multiple targets

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a workspace with 2 projects. The first project is base project. The second contains first project linked as framework.
How to write a podspec for second project? This is my podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name         = "Core"
  s.version      = ...
  s.summary      = ...
  s.description  = ...
  s.homepage     = ...

  s.license      = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE.txt"}

  s.author       = ...

  s.platform     = ...

  s.source       = ...

  s.source_files  = ...

  s.dependency 'RxSwift', '~> 3.0.0'
  s.dependency 'RxCocoa', '~> 3.0'
  s.dependency 'ObjectMapper'
  s.dependency 'Moya', '8.0.0-beta.5'
  s.dependency 'Moya/RxSwift'
  s.dependency 'MTDates'
  s.dependency 'CryptoSwift'

  s.subspec 'Child' do |cinema|
    cinema.source_files = ...
    cinema.resources    = ...
    cinema.frameworks   = "Core"
  end

end
```

But when I tried to lint it, I got the error "no such module 'Core'"